# Is copy or move constructor of std::string called when I return string literal?

Tags: c++, stdstring

Suppose we have those two functions:

```
std::string foo()
{
    return "myString";
}
```

and

```
std::string goo()
{
    return std::string("myString");
}
```

I am thinking that in `foo` the string will be constructed, then copied and then returned while in the second it will be constructed and moved.

Am I correct? Or both cases are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on `NRVO/RVO` and c++ standard (move or copy constructor).

But both cases are the same.

In one you have implicit conversion to `std::string` but in second case you have explicitly created an object:

```
return std::string("myString");
```

[What is (N)RVO and copy/move elision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: Yeah but since in the first case we have the additional step of the implicit conversion, wouldn't that make the second case just a tiny bit faster?

Comment: They are the same because in first case compiler will do the same as you do in second case - it will create an object by passing "myString" to it's constructor. Here is no difference. Just in second case you wrote this explicitly while in first case compiler will do that for you.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you!